# Undefined Index : name while processing this AJAX Code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputdata = $('#iname').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get.php",
            data: inputdata,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("data" + data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This Code Shows the Error Undefined index : name.
This is My form method.
    
    
    add
    
This is Get.php Code :

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: POST key-value pair, object `var inputdata = {name: $('#iname').val() };`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set key and value inside data variable object   **name : inputdata**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputdata = $('#iname').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get.php",
            data: {
                name : inputdata
            },
            success: function (data) {
            alert("data" + data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post your html or #iname input and #add button

Comment: I have tried with var inputdata = $('#formid').serialize();

Comment: <body><form Id="pass" method="post"> <input type="text" Id="iname"> <button id="add">add</button></form>

Comment: I think I have found the problem, post on self page working with action="#" but not working while passing to another page action="action.php" any solution for this????

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the Solution but not the reason this is due to .htaccess file. i have created. in my application after removed the file working fine without any issues.. i don't know why this happen if you know please solve this

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

#error documment..
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/error/403
```